# Ford fusion throttle body?

Tags: ford, rpm, throttle, fusion

I have a manual-transmission 2008 Ford Fusion SE. It's a great car but I have been having some problems with it recently. Firstly, the throttle does not seem to close when I let off the gas pedal. If I take my foot off the gas pedal without taking the car out of gear, The engine RPM does not decrease at all and the car will carry along at its current speed. Putting the car in neutral makes the RPM increase until I come to a complete stop, where the engine finally begins to run at its idling RPM. How should I go about diagnosing this problem? (copied that bit from another one cuz its the same question.) IS the problem with the throttle body? ive read up that they are known for going out. can someone help because im on a budget and dont want to spend a bunch of money on unessessary things.